# jQuery backword Countdown from Initial HTML Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a initial timer value. How can i make it so that it start counting down to 0?

I want the output to get displayed in another element

```
<span id="time">03:30:00</span>
<span id="output"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var val = $("#time").html();
        var output = "";

        // count down

        $("#output").html(output)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var val = $("#time").html().trim();
        console.log(val);
        val = val.split(":");
        var hr = parseInt(val[0].trim());
        var mn = parseInt(val[1].trim());
        var sc = parseInt(val[2].trim());
        console.log(val);
        var timer = setInterval(function(){                 
            if(hr==0 && mn==0 && sc==0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
            }
            if(sc==0){
                sc=60;
                mn--;
            }
            if(mn==0 && sc==0){
                mn=60;  
                hr--;
            }

            sc--;
            $("#output").html(hr+":"+mn+":"+sc);
        },10);

    });

</script>
```

Comment: sorry for not specifying. i want a backward timer.

Comment: Being a programmer, atleast you can do it yourself.
BTW mark this as Correct answers please.

Comment: @jijeshAj have a look now

Comment: when i set time 00:00:10 ..it runs from -ve .eg:  -1:58:30

Comment: @jijeshAj, it should work fine now, according to your requirement :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62104/discussion-between-gahse-and-jijesh-aj).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct answer but rather a best practise

You should use the new time element instead

```
<time datetime="2014-08-29T20:00:00.000Z">3 minutes left</time>
```

where `datetime` is the ISO date format for when the correct moment occured in the future
then inside of the element you would present the text how every you want to display it

By doing so you eliminate the slow bandwidth/DOM parsing & javascript compilation to when its start to count down.

When it has begun you should calculate how many hours/minutes/second there is left until that point in the feuter in every digest.
Then you are safe from the incorrect setTimeout/setInterval that doesn't always wait the exact same time, especially when the tab is idle (in the background)
where `setTimeout(fn, 1000)` could take 4 seconds if it where in the background.

---

Here is a example.

How you get the date and display it in the DOM is up to you

```js
var finishDate = new Date(Date.now()+10000); // get point in future somehow

var tick = function() {
    var now = new Date()
    var difference = finishDate - now;
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5),
        minutes = Math.floor(difference % 36e5 / 60000),
        seconds = Math.floor(difference % 60000 / 1000);

    console.log(hours, minutes, seconds);
    setTimeout(tick, now.getUTCMilliseconds())
}

tick() // Start the digest
```

Comment: give me a short example.

Comment: @Endless, read his comments below my answer. The stuff you are talking about is, no doubt, is better. but for him, its too difficult. I mean just by reading his question, he seems to me as student or beginner, who is trying to create simple application that is why I gave him that solution

Comment: @gahse Maybe so, thats why i only gave him the logic. And others that search for this will maybe find my solution useful too

Comment: Lets see how many of the visitors will rate your answer. :) Keep helping